# Whats the difference between int * p and int p*?

Tags: c, pointers

Is it valid statement `int P*` ?

Whats the difference between `int * p` and `int p*` ?

---

My attempt : 
As the association of `*` is right to left . So it `int P*` not compiled .

Comment: `int p*` is not valid.

Comment: Come on, you only need to try and compile that to know it's not going to work!

Comment: I compiled this code before posting . But that not works .

Comment: If you have seem `int p*/` it does *not* mean that someone multiplied and divided something, but it means that they ended a comment :p

Comment: if you're trying to use `p*` as a type specifier, then you need to define it somehow with the `typedef` statement near the top of your program. For example, `typedef char* p;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it valid statement `int P*` ?

No, it won't compile.

> What's the difference between `int * p` and `int p*` ?

```
int * p;
```

Here `p` is integer pointer .

And `int p*` is an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
int P*
```

or

```
int P*;
```

are both neither a valid declaration or a valid statement.

To declare a pointer to `int` named `P` the correct declaration is:

```
int *P;
```